# Java The method is undefined for this type

Tags: java, class, heapsort

I am having a problem with calling a method that is in a different class. This `main` method is in a class on its own called `lab14`, and the `heapSort()` method is in a different class called `HeapSort`. Both of these classes are in the default package. I am getting the error "The method heapSort(Vector) is undefined for the type Lab14" and I don't understand why, please help.

below is the main method in the lab 14 class

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

    Heap myheap = new Heap();
    Vector<StudentGPA> vec = new Vector();
    int []  br = new int[20]; 
    double []  dr = new double[20]; 
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    try {
    //String inputLine; //stores each line from the file
    Scanner scanLine;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("students.in"));
    while (input.hasNextLine()){
    scanLine = new Scanner(input.nextLine());

    int id = scanLine.nextInt();
    //br[i] = id;
    String name = scanLine.next();
    double gpa = scanLine.nextDouble();
    //dr[i]= gpa;
    //myStr.add(name);
    if(scanLine.hasNext())
    {
         String advisor = scanLine.next();
         GraduateStudentGPA grad = new GraduateStudentGPA(id,name,gpa,advisor);
         vec.add(grad);
    }
    else
    {
        StudentGPA reg = new StudentGPA(id,name,gpa);
        vec.add(reg);
    }
    i++;
    j++;
    }
    input.close();
} 
catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println("IOException in reading input file!!!"+e);
}   
heapSort(vec);
}
```

Below is the code for the HeapSort class

```
public class HeapSort <E extends Comparable<? super E>>{
/** sorts the input vector using heap Sort <ul> <li> iterates
 * through each element of the input vector and inserts each
 * element to the heap by calling {\tt heapInsert}.  <li> deletes
 * each of the inserted items by calling {\tt heapDelete} the
 * appropriate number of times, and fills up the vector with the
 * returned elements.  </ul> If you are using the
 * minheap implementation, this insertion and deletion of all
 * items will produce a list of items sorted by their key
 * attribute values.
 * @param vec input vector
 */
public void heapSort(Vector<StudentGPA> vec){
    //  --  TO COMPLETE  --
    Heap myheap = new Heap<E>();
    for(int i = 0; i <vec.size(); i++)
    {
        myheap.heapInsert(vec.elementAt(i));
    }
    for(int i = 0; i <vec.size(); i++)
    {
        vec.setElementAt((StudentGPA) myheap.heapDelete(), i);
    }

}


}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have several issues going on here.

1. You call `heapSort(vec);` from within the static `main` of class `Lab14`. This would mean that the compiler expects a method matching signature `static void heapSort(Vector<StudentGPA> vec)` within the `Lab14` class. Up to you how you solve that.
2. Change `Vector<StudentGPA> vec = new Vector();` into `Vector<StudentGPA> vec = new Vector<>();`. Note that addition of the angular brackets `<>`.
3. There are actually many more problems, possibly because it is still an unfinished work. Probably I should stay focused on your original question, for which 1./ is the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You gave the answer:

you're trying to call `heapSort` method from `Lab14` class, but `heapSort` method is defined on a different class. The compilation error must be on this line.-

```
heapSort(vec);
```

You need to instantiate a HeapSort object, and then call its `heapSort` method like this.-

```
HeapSort myHeapSortObject = new HeapSort();
myHeapSortObject.heapSort(vec);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your heapsort method can be declared static, at least in its current state

```
public static <E extends Comparable<? super E>> void heapSort(Vector<StudentGPA> vec) {
```

You can then access it in your main method like this

```
HeapSort.heapSort(vec);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to either:

1) make the heapSort method public ***static***... and invoke it as HeapSort.heapSort(vec)

or
2) Invoke the method as new HeapSort().heapSort(vec)